# FQL query for finding public event

Tags: facebook, location, facebook-fql, latitude-longitude, facebook-events

I would like to execute an FQL query for retrieving all the public events in a specific area (using  longitude,latitude and maximum distance or simply location name). Do you know if it's possible?

Apparently, somebody is able to do it, somehow: http://elmcity.info/fb_events?location=tokyo

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get event list based on location](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9339936/get-event-list-based-on-location)

Comment: You will find your answer in this question.  http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9339936/get-event-list-based-on-location Hope it still works!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible indeed to receive events using location based "search"
To do so you'll need the longitude and latitude coordinates of the location you want to search and a access_token with user_events permission (i think you could also use the public search)

Here's an FQL example how can you get all the events nearby of a location. (this searches from your and your friends events):

```
$lat = "40";
$long = "30";

// using offset gives us a "square" on the map from where to search the events
$offset = 0.4;

$events = 'SELECT pic_big, name, venue, location, start_time, eid FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND start_time > '. $created_time .' OR uid = me()) AND start_time > '. $created_time .' AND venue.longitude < \''. ($long+$offset) .'\' AND venue.latitude < \''. ($lat+$offset) .'\' AND venue.longitude > \''. ($long-$offset) .'\' AND venue.latitude > \''. ($lat-$offset) .'\' ORDER BY start_time ASC '. $limit;
```

The trick itself lies in the venue.longitude and venue.latitude useage. To get events from a city, just get the city coordinates and adjust the offset to your needs.
If you don't know how to use FQL please look into [Facebook PHP SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm wrestling with this same problem right now. It does not look possible. There are several problems I see:

- <s>the location fields are not searchable in the `page` or `place` tables,</s>
- the way event locations are populated is inconsistent: See [this page's events for an example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20eid%2C%20location%2C%20venue%20%20FROM%20event%20WHERE%20eid%20IN%20%28%20SELECT%20eid%20FROM%20event_member%20WHERE%20uid%20%3D%20213367312037345%20%29%20ORDER%20BY%20end_time%20asc). (I personally populated most of these. These are FB changes, not user error.),
- FQL does not have an `AS` statement to query based on the result of a calculation, and
- Facebook limits the amount of items returned by a query to some fairly low value.

What the referenced site seems to do is query `event.description` for the presence of the input string. Query "IKEA", and you'll get lots of results. Definitely not a geo search. (BTW, the site's source code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/judell/elmcity)).

**Edit:**

Okay, I was wrong. Facebook does expose a search method, but only in the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#searching). Using the [batch request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) functionality, you could execute a series of requests that:

- Find all `place` entries within a distance (in meters) of a known lat/long. The graph api accepts `q=*` for the search string to return all places.
- Query `event` to find all events at the places returned above.

I'm going to play with this. I'll update this post again as I flesh out this code better.

Comment: You're perfectly right. I really don't understand why limiting the research to the description field. That API would be much more powerful!

Comment: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9339936/get-event-list-based-on-location has a good way to get events by location.  Hope it still works!!

Comment: @DMCS That's a good one. I'll have to give it a try to see if it still works.

Comment: I've tried it:
1) Is it my impression,or it's extremely slow?
2) it gives you the possibility to retrieve only event where your friends are going to. It is quite limiting.
Anyway better than nothing

Comment: @cpilko, can you post an example as soon something start working? I will do the same If I'm able to get it right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this code worked for me returns all details of the upcoming public  event which contains a specific key word that can be your location

```
SELECT eid,name,description,venue,creator,location,ticket_uri,start_time, eid,host,not_replied_count,pic_square,pic_big,unsure_count,attending_count,declined_count,all_members_count FROM event WHERE start_time > now() AND CONTAINS("your location name") AND privacy='open'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in http://elmcity.info/fb_events?location=tokyo they are not really searching for events in Tokyo, they simply executing a query like this

https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=event&q=tokyo

(access token is needed, see https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=search%3Ftype%3Devent%26q%3Dhaifa)

Note that this url also works
http://elmcity.info/fb_events?location=sport

I'm also looking for a way to retrieve public events using fql and so far I didn't find any.